# Errors in good syntax after using new machine

Tags: java, jboss, syntax-error

I have imported project to my new machine (to eclipse) and it threw 88 errors even that on previous machine it was working good. here are the types of errors:

```
MINUTES cannot be resolved or is not a field 
Syntax error 
Method not applicable to arguments
isEmpty() undefined
```

And when I check it all of syntax is good etc.

Anyone had similar problem?

Here's code which throws an exception (MINUTES cannot be resolved or is not a field )

```
try {
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(Config.DOCS_CHECK_INTERVAL);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Exception", e);
    }
```

Imports:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.ikubasienki.core.Config;
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell whether there's anything wrong without seeing the code. I also suspect those aren't the *exact* errors given the typo in "aplicable". It's possible that you're using a different version of the JRE or language. Please show a [mcve]...

Comment: Looks like you use a wrong Java version, e.g. Java 7 instead of Java 8.

Comment: Can you Show your imports too?

Comment: Edited to add an imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your errors suggest that you are using an outdated Java Version. For example, in Java 5, there was no `TimeUnit.MINUTES`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html. It has been added in Java 6.

Assumed that you are calling `isEmpty()` on a `String` Object, the same is true: `String.isEmpty()` has been added in Java 6: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty(), hence you would get an `isEmpty() undefined` error when building the project with Java 5.

Please check the settings of the "JRE System Library" you are using to build the project in Eclipse:

[image: JRE System Library]

Verify that the path shown for the jar files matches the java runtime you want to use.

If that still does not help, create a new Project in Eclipse with a simple class like

```
package com.example;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.err.println("".isEmpty());
    }
}
```

and run it. The output should be something like

```
1.7.0_80
true
```

Another common source of errors is the **Compiler Compliance Level** setting of your project:

[image: Compiler Compliance Setting]

However, this would not explain the "undefined symbol" errors since it affects the language level only (e.g. whether `enum` or generics are allowed). It might explain your syntax error, though.

Comment: Compiler compilance level is also 1.7

Comment: Then, please double check and compare the project settings of your "simple" project and of the project you imported - make sure that you are **really** using the same JRE.

Comment: same, before asking on stack overflow 3 programmers said to me that my problem is java version mismatch, but as we see it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom jre in eclipse points to jre folder (**if you're using jde make sure twice it's not ponting to jde but to jre inside jde!!**)!